# what is the ttys000 or ttys008 mean in iTerm2

Tags: linux, iterm2

When I open my iTerm, there always a 'ttysxxx' on my top bar.

I am so confused about the meaning of it. Does this just mean the number of the shell that I open?

Comment: I suggest reading a good book on Unix basics. Maybe Bach, Maybe Stevens,  Or Just Kernighan.

Answer (score 5):

**(TeleTYpewriter, TTY)**
Teletypewriter originally and now also means any terminal on Linux/Unix systems.

Yes, these are your numbered shell/iTerm sessions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you open new sessions you can see the ttys number increase from: ttys000 to ttys001 and so on.